# Why is adding objects to an array in a loop adds the same object many times?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, loops, express

I'm building a sort of a calendar app in ExpressJS and TypeScript and i have this function that handles events that happen periodically, before sending a response with an array of events for a requested month.

```
let response: TEventResponse[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        let e = events[i];
        if (!e.isPeriodical) {
            const event: TEventResponse = {
                beginning: e.beginTime,
                ending: e.endTime,
                title: e.title,
                description: e.description,
                place: e.place,
            };
            response.push(event);
        } else {
            let beginning = new Date(e.beginTime);
            const upperDate = new Date();
            upperDate.setFullYear(year);
            upperDate.setMonth(month + 1);
            upperDate.setDate(1);
            const lowerDate = new Date();
            lowerDate.setFullYear(year);
            lowerDate.setMonth(month);
            lowerDate.setDate(1);
            console.log(lowerDate);
            console.log(upperDate);

            let dateBoundary = undefined;
            if (e.dateBoundary) {
                dateBoundary = e.dateBoundary;
            } else {
                dateBoundary = upperDate;
            }
            console.log(dateBoundary);

            if (dateBoundary >= upperDate) {
                const periodicalEventsArr: TEventResponse[] = [];
                while (beginning <= dateBoundary && beginning < upperDate) {
                    if (beginning >= lowerDate) {
                        const event: TEventResponse = {
                            beginning: beginning,
                            ending: e.endTime,
                            title: e.title,
                            description: e.description,
                            place: e.place,
                        };

                        periodicalEventsArr.push(event);
                        console.log(periodicalEventsArr);
                    }
                    const n = e.repeatPeriod!;
                    switch (e.repeatPeriodUnit) {
                        case "DAY":
                            beginning.setDate(beginning.getDate() + n);
                            break;
                        case "WEEK":
                            beginning.setDate(beginning.getDate() + n * 7);
                            break;
                        case "MONTH":
                            beginning.setMonth(beginning.getMonth() + n);
                            break;
                        case "YEAR":
                            beginning.setFullYear(beginning.getFullYear() + n);
                            break;
                    }
                    console.log(periodicalEventsArr);
                }
                response.concat(periodicalEventsArr);
            }
        }
    }

    return response;
```

The outer for loop works as it is supposed to but the inner while loop which is supposed to take a periodical event and add it to the array certain amount of times behaves strangely.

It is meant to add the same event many times but change the date each time by a given period of days. It seems to add the event correctly (as the first `console.log(periodicalEventsArr)` shows) but when the date is then updated it changes the value of the 'beginning' field of the event already in the array (as seen with the second `console.log(periodicalEventsArr)`). On the next iteration an event with the updated date is again appended correctly but then after updating the date it changes not only the 'beginning' value of the newly added event but also that value of all the previously added events.

At the end of the loop I'm left with an array in which all the elements are the one that should have been added as the last one.

I have thought about this for quite a while now and I still have no idea what is going on. I would appreciate any insight into what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: FWIW `event` is not a great name for a variable; try something like `myevent`

Comment: `let dateBoundary = undefined;
            if (e.dateBoundary) {
                dateBoundary = e.dateBoundary;
            } else {
                dateBoundary = upperDate;
            }` can just be 
`let dateBoundary = !!e.dateBoundary ? e.dateBoundary : upperDate;`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss why would `myevent` be an improvement and whats bad about `event`. It's not "your" event, it's an anonymous event(response) object and the name is pretty descriptive. I would argue you should never use `my` in variables, that's useful in example code maybe but has no descriptive value elsewhere.

Comment: @zapl On some browsers there is a global variable called `event`. It's bad in the same way as having a variable named `window` is bad - it clashes with an existing variable. Now, it's up to the developer to decide if they want to support IE or older versions of Edge but your users will use whatever browser they have.

Comment: @zapl `myevent` as a name IS just a sample for illustration. only the OP knows for example if they are PartyEvents or BridgeJumping events or SportingEvents or ScheduleEvents etc. 'event' is typically used as part of the JavaScript Event() system such as this code fragment `function eventHandler(event) {`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss ok, that's a good reason not to use `event`. But I guess to have actual problems you have to compile to es5 to run into issues with `var`'s scope or actually want to use the global event

Comment: I don't care much for variable names or browser compatibility as this is only supposed to be for my own use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you always add the same object, `beginning` and at each case you change its state, which ruins the earlier array items. Let's reproduce the problem in simple terms:

```js
let beginning = new Date(); //a new Date
let myArray = []; //a new array
myArray.push(beginning);//let's add this date to the array
console.log(myArray);//and viola! It shows the current day
beginning.setFullYear(2001);//let's go back to the past with the date object
console.log(myArray);//and the already added array item changed
```

So, what should we do instead:

```js
    let beginning = new Date(); //a new Date
    let myArray = []; //a new array
    myArray.push(beginning);//let's add this date to the array
    console.log(myArray);//and viola! It shows the current day
    beginning = (new Date(beginning)).setFullYear(2001);//let's go back to the past with the date object
    console.log(myArray);//and the array item is unchanged
```

So, how to apply this in your case:

```
                        const event: TEventResponse = {
                            beginning: new Date(beginning), //we "clone" the date instead of passing the exact same object
                            ending: e.endTime,
                            title: e.title,
                            description: e.description,
                            place: e.place,
                        };
```